# Building my own SqlDataReader object

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I need some help.  I've been back and forth on which direction I should go and there are some options of which none I like or can use.

I wrote a generic data dump tool that pulls data from a specified server and dumps it to a comma delimited file.  It's configuration and what query to run comes from a SQL table created specifically for this tool.  However, I have a new requirement that there are some data dumps that need data pulled from different servers and merged together, but I don't want to alter the tool for this "custom" type of pull/dump.  I'm trying to keep it generic so I'm not constantly coding on it.  My thought is to create a lib in which my reporting tool can use for each of these custom type of pulls and the data returned by this lib is a SqlDataReader object.   However, since this lib will have to pull from different servers and merge the data, is it possibly for the lib to create a SqlDataReader of it's own with this pulled data and returned to the data dump tool or am I think too much into this?

I don't want to return an array because it's not how the tool loops through data now, mainly because some of my existing data dumps are millions of rows, so my existing loop is a datareader loop to keep memory down.   However, the libs may create a two dimensional array, as long as it can be converted to a SqlDataReader object before returning.  This way I don't have to change much on the looping within my application.

Hope that all makes sense.  I have it in my head bouncing around so I ended up writing this like 10 times.

Edit: Keep in mind, each record will be scattered across 3 servers and have to be merged.  These are three different processes that work together, but have their own servers.  ID from server 1 will relate to Server1ID on Server2 for example.

Comment: If you're writing something 10 times perhaps you need to look at doing something with Design Patterns as well as Refactoring your code / Implementing Interfaces for specific functionality that will be specific to the existing project without affecting the original state of your code.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez this is a service that pulls and dumps data, that wouldn't help as record 1 is scattered across all servers and needs to be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution.   I'll write the object, which will by dynamic based on the "custom" report to be generated.  This object will pull data from the first server and insert it into a local table/SQL Server.  It will then go to the next server, pull data based on the first data pulled and update it within the same server.  Then finally the last server to pull the final data that will also need to be merged into my local table.  Once all that is merged correctly, I'll select * back as the DataReader needed to the original caller Data/Dump exe.  Seems to be the only real way to make this work without modifying the the original exe for each custom data pull.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

All the ADO.NET data access classes implement common interfaces so you can return an `IDataReader` instead of `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Question would still remain, can I create one IDataReader object with data I have from 3 different servers?   Keep in mind, these three servers are giving me different parts of data, so record one will be scattered across all 3 servers.

Comment: You could create a class which implements `IDataReader` if you wanted although depending on what database you are targeting there are probably already C# client libraries for it (such as MySql, Oracle, SQLite, PostgreSql etc).

Comment: I might not be clear on my direction. Let me try this, is it possibly to take a string array and insert it into an IDataReader?